# How to share SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema using managed/reader account?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, reader

I am trying to share my Snowflake Database(default metadata)--> Account_Usage schema --> Query_History table to another managed account (i.e. reader account) but the data is not visible in another account. 
is there any way to share the snowflake database without duplicating the data?

I am getting error as Already Imported Database (i.e) SNowflake cannot be shared for Datashare option.

for a Managed account for usage, I Snowflake database and schemas are available but are not able to see the data which is available.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish by sharing the SNOWFLAKE share to a reader account?  The data relates to the account that it is in and is in fact a share of its own from Snowflake to your account.

Comment: Hi Mike, I want to share the provider metadata for analytics purposes. at the same time, I want to abstract the query data from the reader account.

Answer (score 1):

According [to the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-share-consumers.html#general-limitations-for-shared-databases)  you can't re-share any database that is shared with you:

> Shared databases and all the objects in the database cannot be forwarded (i.e. re-shared with other accounts).

Since the Snowflake database is one that is shared to you from Snowflake, this is probably why you're having issues.

If you need to do this your best bet is to create a table and populate it with the data you need from the Snowflake database and share that table instead. Although it is strange that you'd want to share this info with another account.

Comment: Thanks, Simon! I read through the documentation and get this point. trying to find an alternate way to achieve this. creating the table and populating the data will need multiple data refreshes. and the analytics i will be doing will be visible to account admin in query history. I want this to be abstracted.

Answer (score 0):

Your other option would be to create database/schema in your account with views over the account usage data that you want to share, create a role that can access only that, and then provide a user login with that role only to the group needing to do analytics on your data.

Comment: Tried this option, in this case, the Analytics user doing with SQL queries are visible in my query history. the purpose of accessing it through reader account is SQL queries to be abstracted and should not visible even to account admin.