# partitions_scanned missing from QUERY_HISTORY

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, query-optimization

I am trying to get from my query history the `pct_table_scan` as

```
select
query_id
, (partitions_scanned / nullif(partitions_total,0)) * 100 as pct_table_scan
from table(information_schema.query_history());
```

from `information_schema.query_history()`. However, I see in the documentation that the `partitions_%` columns are available in the [query_history from the account usage](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) , which I don't have access to, but they are missing from the [information_schema.query_history](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html), which I can access.
Is there any way I can access the `partitions_%` columns from the information schema?

Comment: This question might be related to [How to access snowflake query profile overview statistics via SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71804261/how-to-access-snowflake-query-profile-overview-statistics-via-sql) and [How to share SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE schema using managed/reader account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59467332/how-to-share-snowflake-account-usage-schema-using-managed-reader-account) although I only need a handful of columns, not the entire statistics

Comment: No - you can't somehow access columns that don't exist or which you don't have permission to access

Answer (score 0):

As you see in the documentation, these columns are not available in the output of the table function (information_schema.query_history), so you can't access this information through the function.

You may submit a **feature request** to Snowflake Support to add these columns to the query_history table function.